# How to call common Method to multiple Events

Tags: c#

Hello I have this code:

```
    private void txtNumero_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        CercaCliente();
    }
    private void txtNote_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        CercaCliente();
    }
    private void txtNominativo_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        CercaCliente();
    }
```

How can I write this code in better mode? Thanks

Comment: hmm what i suggest you to edit property of respective controls to point out to single void and delete those other two voids

Comment: Ok I tried last time but it doesn't works, now I tried another time and it works, I added only this:

private void CercaCliente(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two approaches you can choose from, and it depends what type of effort you are ready to do...

first when you bind the event there itself call the method rather than creating handler method for each.

Currently, you are doing -

```
 txtNumero.KeyDown += new txtNumero_KeyDown;
 ..
 ..
 txtNote.KeyDown += new txtNumero_KeyDown;
```

then in your method you are calling this common method 'CercaCliente()'.  you can directly use `func` delegate to call you common method. e.g.

```
 txtNumero.KeyDown += (o,e)=>CercaCliente();
 ..
 ..
 txtNote.KeyDown += (o, e)=>CercaCliente();
```

OR

You can create custom control, derived from textbox, and there you can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this common method

```
private void HandlerMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CercaCliente();
}
```

Then inside your form load Attach this handler method to all events

```
this.txtNominativo.KeyDown += HandlerMethod;
this.txtNote.KeyDown += HandlerMethod;
this.txtNumero.KeyDown += HandlerMethod;
```